# How to refresh cache after persist?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA (EclipseLink 2.5) for persistence. My web app contains AJAX page updates. When a post is saved, the posted content shows up without refreshing the browser. The post have tags associated with it using a OneToMany relationship. These tags are supposed to show up after save too. However, because the cache was enabled I was not able to get the tags.

Here's my code:

```
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public Sqask save(AskTag tags) {
    try {
        Sqask ask = saveAsk(tags);
        return ask;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        return null;
    }
}

public Sqask saveAsk(AskTag tags) {
        Sqask ask = new Sqask();
        ask.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy());
        em.persist(ask);
        em.flush();
        saveTags(tags, ask);
        return ask;
    }

public void saveTags(AskTag tags, Sqask ask) {
        if (!tags.getNask().isEmpty()) {
            NAsk nask = new NAsk();
            NAskPK naskPK = new NAskPK();
            naskPK.setAsk(ask.getId());
            naskPK.setNoun(tags.getNask());
            naskPK.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy().getGuid());
            nask.setNAskPK(naskPK);
            nask.setAsk(ask);
            nask.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy());
            em.persist(nask);
        }

        if (!tags.getVask().isEmpty()) {
            VAsk vask = new VAsk();
            VAskPK vaskPK = new VAskPK();
            vaskPK.setAsk(ask.getId());
            vaskPK.setVerb(tags.getVask());
            vaskPK.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy().getGuid());
            vask.setVAskPK(vaskPK);
            vask.setAsk(ask);
            vask.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy());
            em.persist(vask);
        }

        if (!tags.getForask().isEmpty()) {
            PAsk forask = new PAsk();
            PAskPK foraskPK = new PAskPK();
            foraskPK.setAsk(ask.getId());
            foraskPK.setPrep(tags.getForask());
            foraskPK.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy().getGuid());
            forask.setPAskPK(foraskPK);
            forask.setAsk(ask);
            forask.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy());
            em.persist(forask);
        }

        if (!tags.getAboutask().isEmpty()) {
            PAsk aboutask = new PAsk();
            PAskPK aboutaskPK = new PAskPK();
            aboutaskPK.setAsk(ask.getId());
            aboutaskPK.setPrep(tags.getAboutask());
            aboutaskPK.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy().getGuid());
            aboutask.setPAskPK(aboutaskPK);
            aboutask.setAsk(ask);
            aboutask.setCreator(tags.getAskedBy());
            em.persist(aboutask);
        }

        em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Sqask.class, ask.getId());
        em.merge(ask);
}
```

How can I get things to work? How to refresh an entity with all its associated entities? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the point of evicting and then merging the ask instance when the preceding code doesn't seem to modify the ask instance at all.  Assuming saveTags is in the same transaction, ask is still managed so there is no reason to merge anyway, and the transaction hasn't committed, so there is nothing to evict from the shared cache.  My guess is you are setting one side of bidirectional relationships and just need to set the relationship on the ask entity as well.  Em.flush(); em.refresh(ask); would work as well, but cause an unnecessary database hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly maybe this could help you - please notice em.refresh call before returning. This ensured that all OneToOne and OneToMany joins are refreshed, even if you are only saving an ID of related record.

```
public T create(T entity) {
  em.persist(entity);
  em.flush();
  em.refresh(entity); // this could be important
  return entity;
}
```

Comment: Yes that was how I solved my problem. Why I needed to add that flush(); before refresh?

Comment: Flush ensures that change is written into DB (transaction is comitted) and refresh is needed in case you have @JoinColumn fields.
For example: You can have an entity Vehicle which has fields - manufacturerId and also manufacturer (which is of class Manufacturer - and is in fact an object). After you save the record (giving the ID of manufacturer), and when it's refreshed - "manufacturer" object will be available to you. I hope I'm making sense here ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be an AJAX cache problem as well. The reason is if your using javascript for AJAX, you could end up with caching issues. Just check it.. If you think the problem is with JPA cache, working around entity manager with flush and refresh will solve the issue

Comment: Hi I was using JSF 2.2 for ajax. I have tried and found actually the backend wasn't updated.

Comment: So you figured out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not pretty sure whether it will work or not but please  try this
>   in your code if its the problem of backend.

```
em.merge(ask);
 ask.getId();
```

> or

```
 em.merge(ask);
 ask.getId();
 ask.getCollection1ofAsk().size();
 ask.getCollection2OfAsk().size();
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

After added em.flush() before em.refresh(ask), the code worked as I intended. It fetched the lists related to the entity ask. Could anyone explain why? Thanks very much