# EclipseLink doesn't update entity relations after persist

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

**Situation:**
I have two entities related with a onetomany/manytoone relationship.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA{
  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name="tableb_fk_id")
  private EntityB entityB;
}

@Entity
public class EntityB{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityB")
  private List<EntityA> entityAList;
}
```

Imagine a PK called id and getter and setter being there for each class, too.

This is how i persist and read them:

```
public void persist(Object entity){
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  entityManager.persist(entity);
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public EntityB getEntityB(Object id){
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  EntityB entity = entityManager.find(EntityB.class, id);
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
  return entity;
}
```

Now to get the persisted EntityB related to the persisted EntityA i call following:

```
getEntityB(entityA.getEntityB().getId());
```

**Problem:**
If i create an instance of EntityA and set a relation to an already existing instance of EntityB and persist this new instance all data are correctly saved to the database. But if i request the instance of EntityB from my EntityManager, it will not contain the just persisted instance of EntityA in its list. If i reload my persistence layer and flush it with the data from the database, it is there.

```
EntityA newEntityA = new EntityA();
EntityB existingEntityB = getEntityB(5); // just an example
newEntityA.setEntityB(existingEntityB);
perstist(newEntityA);
EntityB entityBforEntityA = getEntityB(newEntityA.getEntityB().getId());
entityBforEntityA.getEntityAList(); // <- does not contain newEntityA unless i restart
```

**Question:**
Why does my EclipseLink not update the newly persisted relation and how can i make it do that?

Comment: why not post your persistence code where you are doing all of these things, including transaction boundaries, and then people can comment on what you are doing

Comment: @NeilStockton sadly this is for work and i am not allowed to post the actual code. The example-entities are about as complex as my actual entities. they just have different names. I guess i can add the adjusted transation-code, too.

Comment: To refresh an object in JPA you need to call refresh() on it, or execute a Query or find() operation using the refresh query hint. Somthing like this `entityManager.persist(EntityA);  entityManager.refresh(EntityA);`

Comment: @SauliusNext it is not the persisted entity which isnt updated, it is the related entity which was persisted before the new one already. I updated my post

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870686/how-to-refresh-cache-after-persist also check cascade https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany

Comment: @SauliusNext thanks, those both look helpfull. Im gonna let you know if this solves my problem :)

Comment: The problem seems to be you are only setting one side of a bidirectional relationship and expecting JPA to automatically set the other side for you.  If when you call newEntityA.setEntityB(existingEntityB); the existingEntityB.getEntityAList() doesn't contain the A, it won't after persist.  JPA does not do anything with your model; you are expected to maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships yourself so that the cache does not become out of sync with the object model.

Comment: @Chris is there any way to tell jpa to cascade those relations in both directions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you aren't adding the newEntityA to existingEntityB's EntityAList, cascading isn't going to help. You need to add it to the list and merge the existingEntityB - this is where setting cascade merge might help, as it would pick up the newEntityA and insert it in the database without needing to manually call persist.

Comment: @Basti see [this article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side). In short: you are using shared cache which is enabled by default. Eclipselink retrieves persisted entities from this cache (instead db) and in this cache Eclpselink doesn't maintain relationships (only field values) and you have to do in by yourself or disable cache by adding `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` in `persistence.xml`

Comment: @Artem i know about the cacheing but i expected eclipselink to update the relationship of entityB when entityA is persisted in its cache. I defenetly need the cacheing tho, since i ll have to high loading rates otherwise

Comment: @Basti relationship won't be updated. It was a bit confusing for me too. Please see article from my previous comment.

Comment: @Artem well a huge thanks for that hint. That cleared it for me. I just expected it to update those relationships. why else would i even bother to mark the relationships via annotations otherwise. Oh well... Could it be that hibernate actually does that tho? I ve only been working with hibernate so far and it always seemed to work like that, or i just never ran into a situation like that

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this today. Let me welcome myself to the club.

As other answers pointed out, it's a cache problem. You can get around it without having to disable the shared cache by forcing `EntityManager` to fetch entity directly from database:

`SomeEntityWithRelationship ent = em.find(SomeEntityWithRelationship.class, "someEntityPK", Map.of("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS));`

Another option is to simply use the relationship instead of directly persisting the related entity. I.e. if `SomeEntityWithRelationship` has a `Set<RelatedEntity>`, directly add to that `Set<RelatedEntity>` instead of manually instantiating a `RelatedEntity` and calling `entityManager.persis(relEntity)` on it.

Examples use eclipselink.